# what does "the value of units' digit of n" mean?

Tags: algorithm

what does "the value of units' digit of n" mean?

for example:
the value of units' digit of abcd is d or a+b+c+d?
(abcd is a decimal number which equals a*1000+b*100+c*10+d)

the value of units' digit of 5^77 and the value of units' digit of 6^47

which is bigger?

5^77=661744490042422139897126953655970282852649688720703125, 6^47=3742042951225759540014535187298779136

although it is not a question related to algorithm, but it is very important in understanding algorithm.

thx!

Comment: Mathematics? It is the last digit in any given number?

Answer (score 1):

*the value of units* is the last digit before decimal separator:

5^77=66174449004242213989712695365597028285264968872070312 **5**, 6^47=374204295122575954001453518729877913 **6**

Or in another way: that's result of *number % 10*.

Answer (score 0):

The "units digit" is also called the "ones digit" or "ones place". It is the digit with unit value `10^0` - the rightmost digit of an integer, or the digit just to the left of the decimal point.

In the same way, the `10^1` digit is often called the "tens", the `10^2` called the "hundreds", the `10^-1` called the "tenths", and the `10^-2` called the "hundredths".

Therefore, in your example, you would compare the rightmost `5` and `6`.

(Also note it says "digit" and not "digit**s**" - if it were to be the *sum of all digits* I believe it would explicitly say so.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, the  “units digit” of a representation of a number is the rightmost digit of the representation.

For the problem mentioned (that is, which of 5^77 and 6^47 has the larger units digit, when expressed in base 10) the relevant way to look at the units digit is as the value of the number modulo 10.  That is, find out which of (5^77)%10 and (6^47)%10 is larger.  Many languages also have versions of `pow` that take a third parameter, a modulus, and compute a modular exponentiation. (As illustrated below in a snip from ipython interpreter.)  Also see wikipedia's [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) article, which begins by illustrating how to compute (7^222)%10 in your head.

```
In [1]: print 5**77; print 6**47
661744490042422139897126953655970282852649688720703125
3742042951225759540014535187298779136

In [2]: print (5**77)%10; print (6**47)%10
5
6

In [3]: print pow(5,77,10); print pow(6,47,10)
5
6
```